# How to take union and write into the same table?

Tags: mysql, sql, hql

I have a table A with columns (x, y, z) and I have another table B with columns (x, y, z), basically the same schema.

I want to add those rows from B into A, which do not already exist in A, basically after the operation the union of A and B exist in table A.

How do I do that in sql?

I mean I know how to take a union, I was thinking something like :

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE A
(SELECT a, b, c FROM A 
union 
SELECT a, b, c FROM B)
```

but this doesn't seem right as I am selecting from the same table I'm writing into.

Comment: `INSERT IGNORE INTO A SELECT a,b,c FROM B`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to add those rows from B into A, which do not already exist in A.

The idea is to filter *before* inserting into the table:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE A (a, b, c)
    SELECT a, b, c
    FROM B
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                      FROM A
                      WHERE B.a = A.a AND B.b = A.b AND B.c = A.c
                     );
```

Note:  This does not filter out duplicate `NULL` values, but that can easily be handled as well (it just complicates the logic a bit).

You can use `UNION` if you want to create a new table with the combined rows.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `LEFT` join of table `B` to table `A` and get only the unmatched rows which will be inserted to table `A`:

```
INSERT INTO A (x, y, z)
SELECT B.x, B.y, B.z 
FROM B LEFT JOIN A
ON A.x <=> B.x AND A.y <=> B.y AND A.z <=> B.z
WHERE COALESCE(A.x, A.y, A.z) IS NULL
```

The *NULL-safe equal* operator [`<=>`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to) will compare `null`s also.
I assume not all columns contain `null` in the same row.

Answer (score 0):

If you want rows from B to overwrite the matching rows in A, then you could use:

```
REPLACE INTO A (a,b,c) 
 SELECT a,b,c FROM B;
```

Note this only detects "matching" rows as those where the primary key or unique key is the same value.